# Using inheritance instead of typedefs for forward declarability and resulting complications with callbacks

Tags: c++, c++11

Not quite sure how to phrase the title here.

The issue is that I have a class template:

```
template<various parameters> struct Base { ... };
```

And then I have an open-ended set of classes deriving from it:

```
struct A: public Base<some arguments> { ... };
struct B: public Base<other arguments> { ... };
struct C: public Base<different arguments> { ... };
...
```

Importantly, the derived classes add nothing to the Base beyond fixing the template arguments -- not member functions, and especially not member variables. So their binary representation should all be the same. The only reason I'm using inheritance instead of typedefs is that I want to be able to forward-declare A, B, C, etc. (Or more accurately, A, B, C, etc. are defined by clients using a provided macro, and I want, for their convenience, for *them* to be able to forward-declare.) The reason to have A, B, C, etc. at all is to avoid having to write out the template arguments by hand all the time.

The problem is that Base has some functions which have callbacks as parameters, and the callbacks are expected to take references to the class itself as parameters.

So I expect to have callback functions like:

```
void foo (A&, ...);
void bar (B&, ...);
```

And so forth. And in the implementation of the callback-taking functions in Base, I'd like to pass *this as the argument to the callbacks. Quite sensibly, C++ doesn't let me do this, because it's not in general safe to pass base classes around where derived ones are expected. But in this specific case it shouldn't be a problem, because the derived classes add nothing to the base and are merely used instead of typedefs.

So it seems I have three criteria:

- I want the 'typedefs' to be forward-declarable.
- I need to be able to pass the base class to callbacks.
- I want to be able to declare the callbacks using the 'typedefs' rather than the base class.

which are mutually incompatible. (The third criterium is, again, for the convenience of clients, because writing out the template arguments to the base class by hand every time would be annoyingly verbose, and not wanting to have to do so is the entire reason to have the 'typedefs'.)

I see three solutions:

- Drop the first or the third criterium.
- Some kind of ugly and complicated scheme whereby I check what kind of argument the callback function expects, and verify that it's a pseudo-typedef of the base (either by checking that sizeof is the same and by SFINAE that it's derived from the base, or checking for some kind of token inserted by the pseudo-typedef-generating macros, or something of that sort), and then perform a cast.

Are there any better ones?

(C++11 is allowed.)

Comment: Nitpick, but important: You are not deriving from "it", i.e. from the template. Rather, you are deriving from various *different, unrelated* classes `Base<X>`, `Base<Y>`, etc.

Comment: Well, yeah, I'm deriving from various instantiations of the template as applied to various arguments. It's what I meant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Employ the [CRTP idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) and pass the derived class aswell in the template parameters. For the callbacks, simply cast `*this` to the derived type.

```
template<class Derived, other params...>
struct Base{
    template<class F>
    void do_callback_stuff(F func){
        func(static_cast<Derived&>(*this), ....);
    }
};

struct A : public Base<A, other args...>{};
```

Comment: CRTP! Of course. It's refreshing to have a question with an obvious answer for once. (Though worth noting that this is basically a cleaner and more disciplined incarnation of the third, "figure things out and do a cast" solution from above.)

Comment: Follow up question, because I still want to do some static checks on Derived. Is derives(Derived, Base) and sizeof(Derived) == sizeof(Base) a sufficient condition for static_cast<Derived&>(Base&) to be safe?

Comment: @illissius: Try `std::is_base_of<Base, Derived>::value`. It's in `<type_traits>`. That alone is enough. If you absolutely want to make sure that `Derived` is actually derived from `Base` (which should be the case), put a simple static_assert into the class body. `template<...> class Base{ typedef Base<...> this_type; static_assert(std::is_base_of<this_type, Derived>::value, "wrong Derived template parameter!"); };`

Comment: The mechanics of figuring that out isn't the issue. The issue is that it's not in general safe to be casting a *Base* to a *Derived* even if we do know for sure that the Derived really is, well, derived from the Base. The question is whether if we also add the condition that sizeof(Derived) == sizeof(Base), does that form a sufficient condition for the cast to be safe? Or are other pitfalls possible (beyond missing data members)? (And is this kind of thing undefined-behaviour-but-should-work, or is it actually guaranteed by the standard somewhere?)

Comment: @illissius: Are you expecting `Base` to be used by otself without deriving from it? That would be the only situation I could imagine where you can't cast to a Derived class, because there is none... Aside from that, the comparision with sizes will always be true, if the derived class doesn't add any members.

Comment: I'm just paranoid. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

As the others suggested, CRTP could be a solution.

But you should also reconsider when and why at all a callback needs a reference to an object that the dedicated caller of the object doesn't know itself in detail. I want to say: "the class template does not know much about its own details before it was instantiated".

So, check the usage patterns that the callback may have, related to the callers object reference (the instantiated class templates object). And extract a common base class or base interface.

Then derive your class template from that base:

```
struct BaseInterface {

    // HERE, declare anything, that callbacks may use

    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

template<various parameters>
struct Base : public BaseInterface { ... };


void some_callback( BaseInterface& caller, ... );
```

Comment: An inspired thought. But even if it made sense to restrict the interface this way (which it doesn't, but you can't have known), the BaseInterface would still need to be templated the same way and we're back at square one.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a combination of the curiously recurring template pattern and implicit conversion would do the trick:

```
template<typename Derived, various parameters> struct Base
{
  operator Derived&() { return static_cast<Derived&>(*this); }
  operator Derived const&() const { return static_cast<Derived const&>(*this); }
  other stuff;
};

struct A: Base<A, some arguments> {};
```